# Create an unordered list n-levels deep using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

While going through some AngularJS examples, I see how easy it is to repeat and create structures. However, I couldn't figure out how to do the following.

Assume we have a json structure like

```
    {
    "Asia": {
            "India": {
                    "Bangalore": {},
                    "Mumbai": {},
                    "New Delhi": {}
            },
            "China": {
                    "Beijing": {},
                    "Shanghai": {}
            }
    },
    "Europe": {
            "France": {
                    "Paris": {}
            },
            "Germany": {
                    "Berlin": {}
            }
    }
    }
```

What I want to do is - Convert this JSON structure to an Unordered list - **The depth of this kind of structure is not known, and can possibly go deeper.** How do I perform repeats dynamically using Angular JS?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert this json structure to an unordered list"? Can you post an example of what this unordered list will look like? Angular helps you build MVC web apps, not manipulate arbitrary data in javascript.

Comment: <ul>
   <li>Asia
       <ul>
           <li>India
                      <ul>
                           <li>Bangalore</li>
                           <li>Mumbai</li>
                           <li>New Delhi</li>
                      </ul>
........
and so on, I hope you got the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is interested in the "least-effort" way to do this without creating a directive (not that you shouldn't, but just offering a variation), here is a simple example:

http://jsbin.com/hokupe/1/edit

Also here's a blog post and a 10-15 minutes video on how it works:

http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/07/15/angularjs-using-templates-ng-include-create-infinite-tree/

Sample Code:

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="treeLevel.html">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="checkbox"
          name="itemSelection"
          ng-model="item._Selected" />
        {{item.text}}
        <div ng-include=" 'treeLevel.html'"
            onload="items = item.children">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </script>
  <div ng-include=" 'treeLevel.html' "
       onload="items = sourceItems">
  </div>
```

Comment: I created https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-tree which is based on the idea, but without the need to define a template in a script block or seperate it out in another way, but rather lets you do recursive templating directly, which to me looks more clean.

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON is poorly structured, you're using property names to carry data.

What you really want is something like this:

```
$scope.continents = [
   { 
      name: 'Asia',
      countries: [
         {
            name: 'India',
            cities: [
               'Bangalore',
               'Mumbai',
               'New Delhi'
            ]
         },
         {
            name: 'China',
            cities: [
               'Beijing',
               'Shanghai'
            ]
         },
      ]
   },
   { 
      name: 'Europe',
      countries: [
         {
            name: 'France',
            cities: [
               'Peris'
            ]
         },
         {
            name: 'Germany',
            cities: [
               'Berlin'
            ]
         },
      ]
   }
];
```

That said... what it sounds like you're looking to do is create a recursive tree directive of some sort.  That gets a little tricky. You'll need to normalize your structure a bit so you can recursively examine it. Then you'll have to create two directives. One for a list, and one for an item:

Here is an [example of what I mean](http://plnkr.co/edit/6maXLm)...

```
function Item(name, items) {
  this.name = name;
  this.items = items || [];
}

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    new Item('test'),
    new Item('foo', [
        new Item('foo-1'),
        new Item('foo-2', [
            new Item('foo-2-1'),
            new Item('foo-2-2')
          ])
      ]),
    new Item('whatever')
    ];
});

app.directive('tree', function() {
  return {
    template: '<ul><tree-node ng-repeat="item in items"></tree-node></ul>',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      items: '=items'
    }
  };
});

app.directive('treeNode', function($compile) {
  return { 
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<li>{{item.name}}</li>',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      //MAGIC HERE!!!: this will do the work of inserting the next set of nodes.
      if (scope.item.items.length > 0) {
        var children = $compile('<tree items="item.items"></tree>')(scope);
        elm.append(children);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Hi blesh, yeah, I figured the construct is poor. However, in your solution, you are assuming 3 levels of depth - continent, country and city. My problem is that this depth is not known in the beginning, and can be deeper.

Comment: @GFoley83 if you read the entire answer, the tree directive at the bottom assumes n-levels of depth, not just three.

Comment: @blesh I tried to put the JSON you fixed in your plunker but it didn't work for me. can you take a look? http://plnkr.co/edit/bEvFUYz6cPy9bTwawLy5?p=info

Comment: For others passing by here, have a look at: https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-tree, which I would argue is a far more simple approach that even let you do all the types of tree structures you would wan't.